# Add Quartz Source Java Files on the Fly

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have looked around and around for this answer, but I have not been able to find a good answer. I would like to create a system based on Quartz that allows people to schedule their own tasks. I will use a pseudo example.

1. Let's say my main method for my Quartz program is called quartz.java.
2. Then I have a file called sweep.java that implements the Quartz "job" interface.

So in my quartz.java, I schedule my sweep.java to run every hour. I run quartz.java, and it works fine. GREAT; however, now I want to add a dust.java to the quartz scheduler; however, since this is a production service, I don't want to have to stop my quartz.java file, add in my dust.java, and recompile and run quartz.java again. This downtime would be unacceptable.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could accomplish this? It seems impossible because how could you ever feed another java file into the program without recompiling, linking, etc.

I hope that this example is clear. Please let me know if I need to clarify any part of it.

Comment: Actually, you can compile Java files on the fly and instantiate the compiled class, at least using Sun's/Oracle's JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: it is possible to compile, and then instantiate, a class, programatically.

Here are links to example code:

- [how to compile from a `String`](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-processor-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/compiler/CompilerProcessor.java);
- [`CompilerOutput`](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-processor-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/compiler/CompilerOutput.java);
- [`CompilerOutputDirectory`](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-processor-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/compiler/CompilerOutputDirectory.java).

The extracted class is grabbed in the third source file (see method `getGeneratedClass`, which returns a `Class<?>` object).

**HOWEVER**: keep in mind that this is potentially dangerous to do so. One problem, which can be quite serious if you are not careful, is that when you dynamically instantiate a class, **its static initialization blocks are executed**. And these can potentially wreak havoc on your application. So, in addition, you'll have to create an appropriate `SecurityContext`.

In the code above, I actually only ever get the `Class<?>` object and never instantiate it in any way, so no code is executed. But your usage scenario is quite different.

Comment: So, is this not a normal use case for Quartz? It seems like they should have a way to do this right? I mean, they can't expect people to be constantly redoing their program? Am I missing something? BTW, Thank you for your quick suggestion!

Comment: I guess the normal use case for dynamic job generation with Quartz is to propose a variety of "prepared" jobs to the user. At least that is what I have seen so far... I am no Quartz specialist, so maybe there is actually a more elegant solution than my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried any of these but are worth trying .

1) Consider using [Quartz camel endpoint](http://camel.apache.org/quartz.html) . 
If my understanding is right, Apache Camel lets you create the camel routes on the fly.
It just needs to deploy the camel-context.xml into a container taking into consideration that the required classes would be already available on classpath of container.

2) Quartz lets you create a job declaratively i.e. with xml configuration of job and trigger.
You can find more information [here](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/JobInitPlugin).

3) Now this requires some efforts ;-)

Create an interface which has a method which you will execute as a part of job. Lets say this will have a method called

```
public interface MyDynamicJob
{
    public void executeThisAsPartOfJob();
}
```

Create your instances of Job methods.

```
public EmailJob implements MyDynamicJob
{
    @Override
    public void executeThisAsPartOfJob()
    {
        System.out.println("Sending Email");
    }
}
```

Now in your main scheduler engine, use the Observer pattern to store/initiate the job dynamically.
Something like,

```
HashMap jobs=new HashMap<String,MyDynamicJob>();

// call this method to add the job dynamically.
// If you add a job after the scheduler engine started , find a way here how to     reiterate over this map without shutting down the scheduler :-).
public void addJob(String someJobName,MyDynamicJob job)
{
    jobs.add(someJobName,job);
}

public void initiateScheduler()
{
    // Iterate over the jobs map to get all registered jobs. Create
    // Create JobDetail instances dynamically for each job Entry. add your custom job     class as a part of job data map.

        Job jd1=JobBuilder.newJob(GenericJob.class)
                .withIdentity("FirstJob", "First Group").build();   

        Map jobDataMap=jd1.getJobDataMap();
        jobDataMap.put("dynamicjob", jobs.get("dynamicjob1"));


}

public class GenericJob implements Job {

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("Executing job");

        Map jdm=arg0.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
        MyDynamicJob mdj=jdm.get("dynamicjob");
        // Now execute your custom job method here.
        mdj.executeThisAsPartOfJob();
        System.out.println("Job Execution complete");
    }

}
```